# 12.04 to 12.10 Upgrade - Software channels problem

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, software-sources

I tried to update Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10, but I encountered a problem. The files downloaded in the first step of the update. It then went on to the second step, but it failed when it reached "setting new software channels". I am not sure why this happened, but the upgrade process aborted and wouldn't continue.

I would appreciat help please.

Thanks.

Comment: There isnt a lot of information to work on here.  If you have manually installed graphics drivers, remove them.  `ppa-purge` your PPAs.  Then rerun your upgrade.  Let us know the results.

Answer (score 1):

First , open " Update Manager " , then left click on " Settings ". and then click on " Ubuntu Software " . When you done that , change from your homeland Server to " Main Server ". That's all , start again Upgrade to !2.10. Sorry for my bad English , I hope that you understand me. :)

Comment: Hi,I tried changing the server to the main server, but it made no difference. I also tried several other servers without success. When it reaches "setting new software channels", it states the following and closes:W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Peppermint 2 - Release amd64 (20110427)/dists/natty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.